# VB.NET How do I reduce int to 1 decimal place?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the code below to convert the file size in bytes (test file is 31718 bytes) to KB (30.974609375 KB) but I want to display this to one decimal place (i.e. 30.9 KB). How would I do this in VB.NET?

```
New FileInfo(FileName).Length / 1024
```

Thanks

Comment: Your number of 30.974609375 you have stated you would like this to be 30.9. Is this correct? Are you sure you do not what this to round to 31.0? 30.9123456 would round to 30.9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Math.Round(New FileInfo(FileName).Length / 1024,1)
```

Comment: How can that be?  In your example you gave these facts, size = 31718, divided by 1024 = 30.974609375, desired output = 30.9.  The answer you said was perfect gives 31.0.

Comment: He was wrong about the 30.9. Rounding 30.97 will always round up, if it was 30.94 or less it would round down to 30.9.

Answer (score 7):

If it's just display output that you need it rounded for then use a format in the ToString

```
Double.ToString("0.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it truncated, but not rounded (as your example implies), Then use Math.FLoor()

```
   Decimal val = Math.Floor(New FileInfo(FileName).Length / 102.4) / 10;
```